# How to Open a new window in a specific position?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a main window where it has a button, on clicking it, a new window appears, but the

```
WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner
```

makes it appear in the center of the main screen.

the button is part of a section that is created with DockingManager, so it isn't always in one place, depending on where the user has pinned it.

Is there a way to make that window appear just adjacent to the button, so it looks like a popup menu?

Comment: For such scenario, opening a new window is overkill. Rather, opening a [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/popup-overview) is better and easier.

Comment: A popup menu that appears next to a given control? Rather sounds like you want a context menu. Buttons already have a specific purpose in windows. Maybe you should associate this menu with some other piece of UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A popup is better than loading a new form and show it next to the button. However, if you insist going with your scenario, you could first get the button’s position relatively to your main form and set the new window location accordingly. To do so, try this code:

```
Point buttonPosition = myButton.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), ButtonWindow);
MyWindow wnd = new MyWindow():
Wnd.Left = buttonPosition.Left;
Wnd.Top = buttonPosition.Top;
Wnd.Show();
```

Comment: Thank you Prefetcher. You saved me :)